# How do I make a JSONP call with JQuery with Basic Authentication?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, basic-authentication

Using JQuery, how would I call a JSONP API that required basic authentication?

Can I programatically handle this, or does the user have to interact and enter the username and password into the logon dialog?

Comment: I found this today, maybe it helps?
http://kevinkuchta.com/_site/2012/01/basic-authentication-with-jsonp/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JSONP request does not use the XMLHttpRequest Object / System. Hence there is no way to do this directly.

I tried several times the approach mentioned in FinnNk's answer, but finally gave up after reading [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/social-actions-dev/browse_thread/thread/423b5b091bdb1656) on the JQuery mailing list.

**Update**

When I said "no way to do this directly", what I meant is:

- You can't programmatically  set the HTTP auth credentials (However, most browsers I have tested will prompt the user for credentials)
- If you don't want the user to enter the credentials manually, you need to use a server to proxy your request. See [this blog post](http://personalized20.blogspot.com/2009/04/created-oauth-crossdomain-javascript.html) for an excellent description and example.

Comment: Your link is broken. Good observation however re XMLHttpRequest. Not sure why @FinnNk's answer would have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

it is a little confusing since http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON doesn't have the same options as docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

the source code link is broken in the post referenced by @HRJ, try these:
https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy
or
https://oauth.net/code/

EDIT: I did manage to find the (now outdated) source code:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/xdoauthproxy/