# How can you redirect to a logon page for cross-domain requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, cross-domain

In an application where I am making cross-domain JSONP requests (using jQuery), when the browser makes the first jsonp request, it pops up a dialog for basic authentication, because that is what the target server requires. I would instead like to trap the event and bring up a dialog with a logon page from the server hosting the resource to establish authentication.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Adeel... it can't be trapped.

However, you *can* supply the required authentication header manually - to prevent the prompt from ever appearing - if the user has already "logged in" and you know their un/pw on the client side.

Comment: Well, if it can't be trapped, it can't be trapped. Following this answer, I think what I should do is bring up a popup dialog with the login page of the target server prior to any calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, only option is to disable basic authentication and for end users, shouldn't that be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Per this thread [How do I make a JSONP call with JQuery with Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640391/how-do-i-make-a-jsonp-call-with-jquery-with-basic-authentication) it seems like you would need to proxy all the requests through server-side to detect and override http-level authentication challenges.