# Cross origin GET from local file://

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, github-api

I'm trying to build an html file to monitor some things on a remote site- specifically, github.com.  I'd like to be able to keep it to just that flat file, making the requests straight from the JS to github's API.  My thought process went like this:

1. Let's use jsonp, since I only need read access, so sticking with GETs should be fine.

   - That fails because you [can't do basic authentication with jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640391/how-do-i-make-a-jsonp-call-with-jquery-with-basic-authentication).
2. Ok, I'll use Github's OAuth instead of basic authentication!

   - That fails because the browser doesn't like me redirecting to a local resource: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/...` for understandable security reasons.
3. Ok, I'll load Github's oauth in an iFrame, then get the resulting url (which should contain the oauth code I need).

   - That fails because you apparently can't access anything about a child iframe if it's on another domain, so unless I redirect back to file:///whatever, I can't get the final url.  And, of course, I can't redirect to file:///whatever because of the ``Not allowed to load local resource` again.
4. Ok, I'll use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (going back to basic auth again)!

   - That fails because CORS from a file:/// url send the origin header as null, [which servers won't accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

So, any suggestions as to how to successfully authenticate to this api from a single, local html file- either as a way around the above tacts, or another idea entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google chrome you could try running it with the

`--allow-file-access-from-files`

switch enabled.

Comment: I don't think that'll help - AFAIK all it does is allow AJAX loading of `file:///` if the origin was also within `file:///`.

Comment: @Alnitak, is running a web server on your computer an option? That's the only other thing I've got left :(

Comment: Yeah, running a web server is the last option, after checking stack overflow.  :)  Related to this answer, I think there's also a chrome option for just allowing cross-origin stuff, although I'd prefer not to have that on when I'm using it for normal stuff.