# CORS issue(403) in Ionic using Scala

Tags: scala, api, ionic-framework, cors, ionic2

I am facing issue in my Ionic app . Rest api is written in Scala which is working properly in Website and Ionic app on browser and on postman . But it is not working on App. I am facing **403 issue** when i am hitting that API.
I tried to update scala config file

```
 cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/api"]
  }
```

Now it is working fine in app but not in browser , What to do ? Is it issue from API end or Ionic code end? My code is as following

```
let params = {"vendor._id":"1"};    
let headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });

     this.http.post('apiurl',params, options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Play framework issue with Cordova. The following link will explain it:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-http-request-with-403-error-on-ipad-device/50269/3

***Reason:***

Cordova sends a request through having header `Origin: file://…`

You can check this link to deal with that 
[Play! 2.4: How to allow CORS from origin file://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509118/play-2-4-how-to-allow-cors-from-origin-file)

Remove default course filter which you import from Play framework and write your condition based filter:

```
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc._
import play.mvc.Http

/**
  * Allow CORS from anywhere, any method
  */
class CORSFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      nextFilter(requestHeader)
        .map { result =>
          if (requestHeader.method.equals("OPTIONS")) {
            Results.Ok.withHeaders(
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type,application, idUser, access-control-allow-methods, token, access-control-allow-credentials, Authorization",
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE")
          } else {
            result.withHeaders(
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type",
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE",
              Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS -> "X-Custom-Header-To-Expose")
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```